# Подшить к 1му массиву непропущенные значения со 2го в R

Tags: r

Основной массив

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), dig = c(2,3,NA,5,NA), let = c("a",NA,"c","g",NA))

  id dig  let
1  1   2    a
2  2   3 <NA>
3  3  NA    c
4  4   5    g
5  5  NA <NA>
```

Массив с новыми значениями

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(2,3,5), dig = c(NA,100,200), let = c("letter1",NA,"letter2"))

  id dig     let
1  2  NA letter1
2  3 100    <NA>
3  5 200 letter2
```

Нужно по id подшить непустые значения из df2. То есть, результат должен выглядеть так:

```
  id dig     let
1  1   2       a
2  2   3 letter1
3  3 100       c
4  4   5       g
5  5 200 letter2
```

Comment: Совершенно не понятно, то ли используется какая-то двумерная конструкция с элементами разного типа, то ли три массива, которые нужно вывести в столбик. Уточните описание задания.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
repl <- which(is.na(df1[1:3, ]), arr.ind=T)
df1[repl] <- df2[repl]
```

Главное - размерности таблиц (исходной и со значениями на замену) должны совпадать, тут я вручную укоротил `df1`.
UPD Более универсальный вариант от автора вопроса:

```
 repl <- which(is.na(df1[df1$id %in% df2$id, ]), arr.ind=T) 
 df1[df1$id %in% df2$id, ][repl] <- df2[repl]
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.
Как универсальное решение вроде бы должно подойти такое

`repl <- which(is.na(df1[df1$id %in% df2$id, ]), arr.ind=T)
df1[df1$id %in% df2$id, ][repl] <- df2[repl]`

Comment: Да, так вообще классно получается.

Comment: @Ogurtsov Вы можете вынести это отдельным ответом, таким образом обратив на него внимание тех, кто столкнулся с такой-же задачей